# MathJax with ASP.Net and Label Controls

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, mathjax

I'm having a difficult time trying to get a MathJax formula to show up.  Here is a CodePen that will at least give a look at the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
      MathJax.Hub.Config({
        tex2jax: {inlineMath: [["$","$"],["\\(","\\)"]]}
      });
    </script>

<div style="position:absolute;width:100%;background-color: #99FF99" class="auto-style1">
        Background Calculations</div>
<br /><br />
    <table class="auto-style2">
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style8">Effective <strong><span class="auto-style7">Cases Produced</span></strong>:</td>
            <td class="auto-style9"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>$$Cases Produced = {\color{red}{\textit{Filled Packages}} \over \color{blue}{\textit{Trays per Case}}}$$</td>
            <td>$$ = {\color{red}{\textit{<asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="######"></asp:Label>}} \over \color{blue}{\textit{<asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="###"></asp:Label>}}}$$</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

The manually typed formula works just fine.  However, I can't seem to get the formula with the Label controls to work.  Mainly, I think, because it will render the text value like this:

```
<td>$$ = {\color{red}{\textit{<span id="Label1">######</span>}} \over \color{blue}{\textit{<span id="Label1">###</span>}}}$$</td>
```

I think, because of how ASP.NET is rendering the Label into a SPAN and not the actual value - MathJax is unable to figure it out?

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: sorry, couldn't post the codepen, but it is basically the same as above anyway.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, cf. https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found was that using a Literal instead of a Label is the way to go.  The code change was:

```
<table class="auto-style2">
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style8">Effective <strong><span class="auto-style7">Cases Produced</span></strong>:</td>
        <td class="auto-style9"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>$$Cases Produced = {\color{red}{\textit{Filled Packages}} \over \color{blue}{\textit{Trays per Case}}}$$</td>
        <td>$$ = {\color{red}{\textit{<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text="######"></asp:Literal>}} \over \color{blue}{\textit{<asp:Literal ID="Literal2" runat="server" Text="###"></asp:Literal>}}}$$</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: For context, MathJax's TeX parser will stop at HTML tags, cf. http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#tex-and-latex-in-html-documents. There are non-standard macros such as `\cssId{MYID}{math}` that might help, cf. http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#html.